# In Angular, how to load template html on demand

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular2-template

I am using angular 4.0  and project is setup using angular-cli. When creating components template is specified  as template url and html is created as separate html file.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'values',
    templateUrl: './values.component.html',
    providers: [ValuesService]
    //styleUrls: ['./values.component.css']
})
```

`angular-cli.json` has outDir listed as separate folder where it creates all the *.bundle.js files when I run `ng build`

When I run build it includes all my html files into the `main.bundle.js` which is making my file size huge.

My question is how to make it load from server as component needs that html file instead all files are pre-loaded

Answer (score 0):

In angular you can load module in demand (lazy loading), but you can not load a single component, you need bring all module where is the component.

You can use loadChildren for charge module in demand and not charge the entire application from beginning. Lazy loading go to backend and brings the module that you selected, but not charge single component, not is possible. Angular work with module

Comment: It doesn't seem right to me. what if I have only one module and many components with lot of html. it can load all the component but lazy load the html as when it needs it otherwise its too big js file at the end.

Comment: I think that if you have one module, it comes complete to frontend, Angular not send to frontend a single component from backend, always send the modulet that contain the component